# Prove that if $p$ is a prime such that $p^2+2$ is a prime then $p=3$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, proof-verification

My problem in my solution is that I don't know if the operations I apply on congruence modulo n are admissible. I could really use some guiding:

Attempt: Let there be $p\ne 3$ fulfilling the requirements aforementioned. Every prime number $p\ne 2,3$ satisfies: $p\equiv1 \mod6$ or $p\equiv5 \mod6$. If $p\equiv1 \mod6$ then $p^2\equiv1 \mod6$ which means  $p^2+2\equiv3 \mod6$ which is a clear contradiction. **Here's the tricky part**(of which I am not sure): $p\equiv5 \mod6$ $\Rightarrow p^2\equiv5 \mod6$ $\Rightarrow p^2+2\equiv1 \mod6$.

That means by definition: $6|(p^2+2)-1$ and $6|p^2-5$ and therefore(?): $6|p^2-4$ deriving $2p^2\equiv 4 \mod 6$ $\Rightarrow p^2\equiv 2 \mod 6$ which is a contradiction.

Comment: $p\equiv5 \mod 6 \implies p^2\equiv 1 \mod 6$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The general idea is correct, but the second implication is wrong, because $5 \equiv -1 \pmod{6}$, hence $5^2 \equiv 1 \pmod6$.

This means that $p^2 + 2 \equiv 3 \pmod6$ for every prime $p > 3$. Since $3 \mid 6$, it follows that $3 \mid p^2 + 2$, i.e. $p^2 + 2 \equiv 0 \pmod3$, for every prime $p > 3$

Comment: Great. 
Without thinking it through I just assumed a remainder of 5. Thank you.

Answer (score 5):

Another way : Consider in mod $3$. If $p\equiv \pm 1$, then $p^2+2\equiv 0$.

Answer (score 3):

If $p\neq3$ then $p\equiv 1\ or -1\ (mod\ 3)$ so $p^2\equiv 1\ (mod\ 3)$ so $p^2+2\equiv 0\ (mod\ 3)$ which shows p is divisible by 3 which means $p^2+2$ is not a prime for p not equal to 3. If $p=3$, $p^2+2=9+2=11$ which is a prime.

Answer (score 2):

Suppose, we have $p\ne 3$. Then, it follows $p\neq 0 \pmod 3$.
This implies $p^2\equiv 1 \pmod 3$. So, $p^2 + 2\equiv 0 \pmod 3$
Because of $p^2 + 2 > 3$, $p^2 + 2$ cannot be prime.